# React Native missing modules after installing react-native-multi-selectbox

Tags: react-native, npm, compiler-errors

I am trying to install the following npm package to use the component in my project: npm i react-native-multi-selectbox#
(react-native-multi-selectbox https://openbase.com/js/react-native-multi-selectbox)

And it's not really a question but I just need help to set this up. Running the command and trying the code in the example means only errors appear. I did nothing different and still, it says that packages are missing

Hope someone has experience with installing such components

[one of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty3DZ.png)

Comment: That's weird... Did you maybe try to install multiple libraries at once? I see that `react-native-multi-selectbox` doesn't have any dependencies at all. I would think that this isn't related. Maybe eliminate any assumption by removing the library and the code that is using it and see if the error disappears.

Comment: Yea sure when I remove the code everything works fine, but I want to use the installed component, thats my problem.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is just to `yarn/npm install` every module that it is missing in the error logs

Comment: Oh god thank u I think it fixed it :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you. I've posted it with some extra explanation as an answer. Please approve it as a correct answer. This will make it easier for other users to find the answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is just to `npm install` every module that it is missing in the error logs. In your case `npm install react-native-svg`

I think the library just assumed that `react-native-svg` is already installed.

There's already an [issue](https://github.com/sauzy34/react-native-multi-selectbox/issues/33) on their Github about this but the issue doesn't have a description (probably the reason why it is closed)